# Where can I find the nav-sections phtml file

Tags: magento2, layout, phtml

I want to customize the `nav-section` component, like changing data, adding more links, and customizing its styling on hover, but I cannot find its phtml or markup file in the Magento theme.

To my knowledge, to customize that component, I just need to find the file, copy it, paste it into my theme folder, and then customize it according to my design.

Is there any way to customize that component without creating it from scratch?

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, let call the `nav-sections` is a div or a section instead of component, component means [UI component](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/).

The template file responsible for the `nav-sections` is [vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml).

To find the template file for the `nav-sections` in Magento codebase, you should find the word `nav-sections` in the **vendor/magento** directory. Here, you will see `nav-sections` CSS class declared in [vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L70) which belongs to template `Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I couldn't find any template file `nav-sections` in `vendor/magento` directory.

Comment: You missed my point. Could you please read my answer again? `nav-sections` is the class name of the div, so we find this class name in magento codebase (vendor/magento). Finally, you will find the template you are looking for is vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml

Comment: Ah, I see, but how do I edit the content of `nav-sections`. So in the luma theme, `nav-section` has the default data like 'First Category', 'Men', 'Women'. So I want to replace that with my own data.

Comment: They are category names, so you can config them in admin (back office): Admin menu > Catalog > Categories > Select a category to edit. So I would recommend you start as a store owner instead of a developer. Starting with documents on Adobe documents https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/start/guide-overview.html or video guides series for beginners: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzdGUmqQ10g&list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9eL59JGE3ny-_GAU-z5X5D&index=17

Comment: After that, you can continue to customize magento site. If you have any questions about magento either as a store owner or a developer, you can ask here. I'm available for hire, if your company needs to hire a magento developer to customize, please refer me. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see, got it. Thank you!